# How to parse curly brace with ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

First of all I don't want to use StringTemplate.

I am learning ANTLR and I have created following grammer.

```
grammar CurlyBracket;

/* LExer Rule */
START_BR : '{' ;
END_BR   : '}' ;
TEXT      : ~[{}]+ ;
TWO_ST_BR : '{{'; 
TWO_ED_BR : '}}';

/* Grammer Rule */
root : html EOF ;
html : ( normal | bracket | tokenbracket ) * ;
normal : TEXT ;
bracket : START_BR html END_BR;
tokenbracket : TWO_ST_BR html TWO_ED_BR;
```

Now Bracket is parsed successfully. But I have following requirement.

1. Want to get all Token that Start with two curly brace.
2. If it is one or more than two then it should not consider.

I have simple input.

```
This is test {Test}  {{User.Test1}} {{{Test2}}}
```

So output should be only

```
   {{User.Test1}}
```